# How do you correctly define entities within a namespace that have been declared in a header?

Tags: c++, namespaces, header-files

Consider a pair of two source files: an interface declaration file (`*.h` or `*.hpp`) and its implementation file (`*.cpp`).

Let the `*.h` file be like the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  class MyClass {
  public:
    int foo();
  };
}
```

I have seen two different practices for using namespaces in source files:

`*.cpp` showing practice #1:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
using namespace MyNamespace;

int MyClass::foo() { ... }
```

`*.cpp` showing practice #2:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
namespace MyNamespace {

  int MyClass::foo() { ... }

}
```

**My question:** Are there any differences between these two practices and is one considered better than the other?

Comment: There's also option 3: Just us the full name, e.g. `int MyNamespace::MyClass::foo() ...`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789163/using-directive-best-practice

Comment: @Dave not duplicate. These questions complement each other. Recommend to add the link provided by Dave as "Read also..." to this question. My question will help novices to choose the correct style.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210935/creating-a-c-namespace-in-header-and-source-cpp

Answer (score 86, accepted):

From a code readability standpoint, it is probably better in my opinion to use the #2 method for this reason:

You can be `using` multiple namespaces at a time, and any object or function written below that line can belong to any of those namespaces (barring naming conflicts).  Wrapping the whole file in a `namespace` block is more explicit, and allows you to declare new functions and variables that belong to that namespace within the .cpp file as well

Comment: The question Dave linked in his comment to your question also outlines some key points in the differences (if any) between the two methods you're looking at

Comment: Guys, I really do not know whose answer to select. They have intersection while complement each other.

Comment: Just commenting to acknowledge that some IDE's like CLion will only detect implementations if you use option/practice #2.

Comment: @PedroTanaka is this still the case? I have not noticed any such problem.

Comment: @JMcF I haven't checked since the time I published the comment. In early versions of Clion the problem occurred.

Comment: The option 3 presented below `int MyNamespace::MyClass::foo() {...}` is working correctly in CLion 2020.2.1

Answer (score 65):

The clearest is the option you didn't show:

```
int MyNamespace::MyClass::foo()
{
    //  ...
}
```

It's also very verbose; too much so for most people.  Since `using namespace` is a recipe for name conflicts, at least in my experience,
and should be avoided except in very limited scopes and places, I
generally use your #2.

Comment: Guys, I really do not know whose answer to select. They have intersection while complement each other.

Answer (score 12):

> Are there any differences between these two practices

Yes. #1 and #2 are examples of a [using-directive](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives) and a [namespace definition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces) respectively. They are effectively the same in this case but have other consequences. For instance, if you introduce a new identifier alongside `MyClass::foo`, it will have a different scope:

#1:

```
using namespace MyNamespace;
int x;  // defines ::x
```

#2:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  int x;  // defines MyNamespace::x
}
```

> is one considered better than the other?

#1 Pros: a little more terse; harder to accidentally introduce something into `MyNamespace` unwittingly. Cons: may pull in existing identifiers unintentionally.

#2 Pros: more clear that definitions of existing identifiers and declarations of new identifiers both belong to `MyNamespace`. Cons: easier to unintentionally introduce identifiers to `MyNamespace`.

A criticism of both #1 and #2 is that they are referring to an entire namespace when you probably only care about the definition of members of `MyNamespace::MyClass`. This is heavy-handed and it communicates the intent poorly.

A possible alternative to #1 is a [using-declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-declarations) which includes only the identifier you're interested in:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
using MyNamespace::MyClass;

int MyClass::foo() { ... }
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd like also to add that if you decide due to some reason to implement a template specialization in a cpp file and just rely on `using namespace` you will run into the following problem:

```
// .h file
namespace someNameSpace
{
  template<typename T>
    class Demo
    {
      void foo();
    };
}

// .cpp file
using namespace someNameSpace;

template<typename T>
void Demo<T>::foo(){}

// this will produce
// error: specialization of 'template<class T> void someNameSpace::Demo<T>::foo()' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
template<>
void Demo<int>::foo(){}
```

Otherwise if you apply #2 method this will be fine.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add one more way, using a *using-declaration*:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
using MyNamespace::MyClass;

int MyClass::foo() { ... }
```

This saves you from typing the namespace name many times, if a class has many functions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the *practice #1* is not correct C++ code at all. This code snippet defines ::MyClass::foo symbol, where the real full qualified name is ::MyNamespace::MyClass::foo.

To learn about namespaces you can read section 7.3 of the draft let's say for standard http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf

This concept is pretty old from 1998 or so, so you can use any standard or books of B.Stroustroup to learn about it.

In C++ language the **namespace** is a named scope. The namespace, as opposed to the class definition, is open to adding new functions to it.

The construction **"using namespace NS;"** in C++ is called as using-directive, and it can be used for several goals in my practice:

1. You can use this directive in another namespace to combine(mix) names from a different namespace.
2. In the context of the compilation unit it appends synonyms to all variables in namespace **NS**.

To define symbol, you can use two mechanisms -
you can use the explicit qualification with all namespaces via operating in global namespace in C++ source file.

Or You can open namespace and add definitions to it (practice #2).