# Import type-alias from class in source

Tags: c++, namespaces, type-alias

How do I import the type alias of a class for general use in my source file?

I.e., consider I have a file `myClass.h` with

```
template<typenmae T>
class myClass {
  using vec = std::vector<double>;
  
  vec some_vec_var;
public:
  // some constructor and other functions
  myClass(T var);
 
  vec some_function(vec some_var);
  void some_other_fcn(vec some_var);
};
```

I've always written my sourcefile (`myclass.cpp`) in the following manner

```
#include "myClass.h"

template<typename T> 
myClass<T>::myClass(T var){/* */} // fine 

template<typename T>
void myclass<T>::some_function(vec some_var){/* */} // fine

// Error: vec was not declared in this scope ... 
template<typename T> 
vec myClass<T>::some_function(vec some_var){/* */} // not fine
```

How do I overcome this? Type aliases tend to become tediously long, so simply replacing vec as return-type with its declared alias is not a feasable solution for me.

Do I need to wrap it around a namespace scope? something like

```
namespace MyNameSpace{
  class myClass { ... };
}
```

as described here: [C++: Namespaces -- How to use in header and source files correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816600) ?

Or can I just import the namespace of the class somehow?

Comment: `typename myClass<T>::vec myClass<T>::some_function(typename myClass<T>::vec some_var){/* */}`. Frankly, I'm more concerned with the whole `myClass` being (a) a template, and (b) implemented anywhere *other* than the header file. Barring explicit instantiation intentions, that's where it belongs.

Comment: Could zou elaborate your concern a little more? I thought it is common practice to write two separate files `*.h` with class and function declarations and `*.cpp` with the actual code.

Comment: @ro_go yes but not with templated classes - these need to be defined in the header file as well, since the compiler instantiates it for the specific types used inside the template; see  [Why can templates only be implemented in header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing return type (C++11) might help:

```
template<typename T> 
auto myClass<T>::some_function(vec some_var) -> vec
{/* */}
```

Else you have to fully qualify:

```
template<typename T> 
typename myClass<T>::vec myClass<T>::some_function(vec some_var)
{/* */}
```